# Python selenium code just stopped working

Tags: python, selenium

I have been testing some code today and it has been working totally fine. It has now just stopped working, I haven't changed anything.

```
action.move_to_element(text_box)
action.click(text_box)
action.send_keys(index)
action.perform()

sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="AC_tRes"]/li[1]').click()

sleep(10) 

link = driver.find_element_by_link_text('Financials')
link.click()
```

This code enters a name into a search box and then goes to that page. It should then click on the Finance page.

It has been working totally fine. I haven't changed anything and now I get the following error:

`selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <a class="link3" href="foo" </a> is not clickable at point (505, 509)`

But I don't understand why it would just stop when I haven't even edited the code.

https://www.marketscreener.com/MICROSOFT-CORPORATION-4835/

I land on this page and it should go to the Financial link. but it is sometimes working sometimes giving me the above error.

Comment: From the exception, looks like, the element you are trying to click is getting obscured by an other element. Make sure that you're running automation on 100% screen size and the element is not getting overlapped with any other element.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes site can take a while to load, way exceeding your `sleep(10)` call.  Hence, the element might not be available for clicking when the line is executed.

You will want to [read the docs on Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html), particularly around Expected Conditions, and rebuild your navigation with that mindset.

Comment: I've tried changing it to sleep(100) to see if that solves it as a test

Comment: That will not solve your problem.  If the page is hung up on loading the element will still not be clickable.  `selenium` gives you plenty of `Wait` methods, it's probably best to use those instead.

Comment: I will have a look. I found the implicitly_wait method. I will also look at the others you suggested.